# Get debugging working with Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools, vscode-debugger, javascript-debugger

I'm working on setting up an environment to get debugging working for my program and I found these instructions online to get it to work with Chrome but I want it to work with Visual Studio Code:

- Open Google Chrome and navigate to chrome://inspect. Your program should be listed as a debuggable target. It'll have your program ID attached to it.
- If you don't see the panel as a debuggable item, you may need to tell Chrome to look at the port you've specified above.
- Click "Configure" next to "Discover Network Targets"
- Add "localhost:9345" (or the port you used above"
- Click "Done"
- Click "inspect". CDT should launch with the full debugging experience

Is this enough information to get debugging to work with Visual Studio Code?

More information when visiting the URL:

```
[
  {
    "description": "Program",
    "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&ws=127.0.0.1:9345/devtools/page/abc123",
    "faviconUrl": "https://www.example.com/favicon.ico",
    "id": "abc123",
    "title": "abc123",
    "type": "page",
    "url": "",
    "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9345/devtools/page/abc123"
  }
]
```

Comment: This is done using `Debugger for extension`, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome. Have you followed all the troubleshooting steps listed on the page?

Comment: @TarunLalwani But the program is not Chrome. The program uses the debugger in Chrome. I want to use Visual Studio Debugger *not* Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Those instructions are not enough for debugging within VSCode.
To be able to debug in VSCode you should add a debug launch configuration:

- Open the debug view (debug icon or Ctrl+Shift+D)

  [image: Debug icon]
- Add a configuration for chrome:
  click the gear icon or manually create launch.json file
  (inside .vscode folder in root of your project)

example launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:9345",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

- Select the newly created config and click the play button ('Start Debugging')

Check out the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) for more information.

Comment: I think I'm getting closer but it's not connecting yet. I'm trying to debug in Brave, Firefox or VSCode not Chrome. I added more information to the post.